# Separate a 200x200 bitmap into 5x5 array

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create 25 bitmap of 40x40 in a 200x200 bitmap (so it's 5x5 bitmap) so I can determine where it's colored by the user draw (See example).

I tried to create 5 row and column of bitmap and insert a portion of the bitmap original (40x40) but i always get the bitmap original in 40x40, is there a way to get the 40x40 first pixel then the 40x40 of the 2nd row etc ?

[image: Example]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didnt try much because i dont know how to do this, i've did some search but i didnt find something close from my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way :

```
private Bitmap split(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
        {
            Bitmap[] bmpArray = new Bitmap[] { };
            Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40);
            Bitmap cloneBitmap = bmpOriginal.Clone(cloneRect, bmpOriginal.PixelFormat);
            return cloneBitmap;
        }
```